# Regex for removing RT

Tags: php, regex

I have the following input string:

```
 "i'm good RT @someone : how are you?"
```

I want to remove everything after `i'm good` for having a final string like below:

```
 "i'm good"
```

Here the regex I had so far:

```
/ RT\s*@[^:]*:\s*[A-Za-z ]/
```

However, only ' RT @someone :' is removed, the status is still on.

What am I missing?

Comment: Add some examples and your attempts too

Comment: '/ RT\s*@[^:]*:\s*[A-Za-z ]/' but only ' RT @someone :' is removed, the status is still on

Comment: e.g. 'i'm good RT @someone : how are you?'    to be   'i'm good'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\s*RT\s*@[^:]*:.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yO3dG8/3)

Comment: how about to make the status is still on if i make the input 'RT @someone: status status status'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. Can you rephrase it please?

Comment: @Jessica ... or simply add your input string to your post with the desired output.

Comment: @Jessica From this sentence `'RT@someone: status bla bla bla'` what do you want to preserve?

Comment: based on your regex above, if I make the input like 'RT@someone: status bla bla bla', the output is gone also...

Comment: how to make the regex? if I want the input/output be like this 
e.g. 'i'm good RT@someone : how are you?' to be 'i'm good'  and 'RT@someone : how are you? to be how are you?

Comment: whereas, your regex has space before RT to make it run. but why does it happen?I dont make space before RT instead on the input.

Comment: I added the space before RT because it appears in the comments of your post. However, the `\s` is followed by the star operator (`*`). So zero or more spaces can be found before RT by the regex. See the picture I added to the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
RT\s*@[^:]*:\s*[A-Za-z ]+
```

You need to add a quantifier like `*` or `+` to remove status as well.

or

```
RT\s*@[^:]*:\s*.*
```